# Can I parse a pdf with powershell, using no extra libraries?

Tags: windows, powershell, parsing, pdf

I would like to parse a pdf with a Windows powershell script. Is it possible to do this without any open source libraries, though? I am in a situation at work that views this as a security risk.

The pdfs are in an expected text format, and I need to extract two numbers from them to be used later.

Sample pdf:

[image: This]

Obviously, the Device ID and Agreement number are crossed off for security, but those are the two strings I care about.

Comment: You could, by implementing a pdf parser *in* PowerShell. That would probably be a waste of time. The real problem you should be solving here is that management (or whoever else at work) views any open source library as an insuperable security risk.

Comment: To put @Mathias' comment into perspective... implementing a pdf parser is more than a day's work, more like a year's...

Comment: In Windows 10 it is possible using the built in UWP libraries. The problem however is getting a result out of the async objects without writing a wrapper class in C#. I've written an OCR powershell script that can also read PDFs, using nothing but built in classes from Windows 10. I did however had to create a small dll to handle async stuff